# Database query for events based on friends going

Tags: sql, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a timeline with events for users.

To build this timeline, I would run a query that does the following:

- returning all events where friends of the user are set to going.

What I have now:

- client-side: a List of all the ids of the friends of a user: ex. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
- server-side: a Firestore collection with all the events:

  events/eventID

  This document has a value 'going' which is a list that contains all the users IDs that are 'going' ex. ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

(As an example, the query should return this document, because 2 friends are going)

A simple solution would be:

Getting all events and comparing the 2 lists on the client-side. Problem: ok for 100 documents, but impossible if the collection scales. (Because Firstore bills on document reads.)

Is there a better way to do this (With Firestore)?

Or is this not possible with Firestore and are there other technologies to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is both a broad and unclear question. You're building a timeline but your data is based on how may friends indicate 'going', which isn't really a timeline. Also, we don't know anything about your data or how that data related. Can you include the code you've attempted, a more clear definition of your data and can you also clarify what's being asked? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update and we'll take a look!

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question, please let me know if it's now clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no code in the question and I don't know the platform so let me answer this at a high level.

Suppose we have a `users` collection:

```
users
   uid_0
      name: Larry
      friends:
         uid_1: true
         uid_2: true
      events_where_friends_are_going:
         event_0:
            uid_1: true
            uid_2: true         
   uid_1
      name: Moe
      friends:
         uid_2: true
      events_where_friends_are_going:
         event_0:
            uid_2: true
   uid_2
      name: Curly
```

and let's say we have a series of events stored in a collection:

```
events
   event_0
      name: "some event"
      signups:
         uid_1: true
         uid_2: true //Curly signed up
```

The process is that when a user signs up for an event, `event_0` for example, they are added to that event collection and then query the `users` collection for all of the other users they are friends with via the `friends` sub-collection. Then they add themselves to the events_where_friends_are_going, creating the event if it doesn't exist, or if it does, add themselves to the list.

In the above structure, if Curly signed up for event_0, as shown in the signups collection, the query reveals they are friends with uid_0 and uid_1. They are then added to uid_0 and uid_1 events_where_friends_are_going collection.

Comment: Thanks ! Looks like a valid solution! But is it cost efficiënt ? Cuz if a user has 100 friends. It would take 101 writes to set going to An event. I Think that would be expensive?

Comment: Thanks! So I think I would go for the realtime database because the writes are free. I planning to make a function that will delete the events that are ended so that I don't have to store much data. I think this setup is what I need, do you think it's scalable and future proof?

Comment: @KarelDebedts The writes are only free if the amount of data is less than the limit - after that you are charged for data. Quantity of data is not an issue as Firebase can easily handle hundreds of gigabytes. So yes, it is scalable.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! What’s the limit for the amount of writes?

Comment: @KarelDebedts Take a minute and review the link to the Pricing I linked above - it covers the charges for all Firebase products. For the RTDB, the limit is for the amount of data, not the number of writes.